# Function to find X numbers that add up to a certain value

Tags: algorithm, lua

I need a function that finds a variable amount of numbers, which together must add up to a certain value. In this case it is 8.

The numbers which can be added together are predefined in a table, to make things easier.
Current approach: Shuffle the table using a small algorithm, add first X values together, if they don't add up to 8, start over (including shuffling again) until the first X values add up to 8.

My code does work, just 2 problems: It takes a long time to process (obviously) and it can cause a stack overflow error if I don't add a cooldown.

Code can be dirty, it's not for a live production. Also im only an intermediate lua developer at best...

```
function sleep (a) -- random sleep function I found
    local sec = tonumber(os.clock() + a); 
    while (os.clock() < sec) do 
    end 
end

function shuffle(tbl) -- random shuffle function I found
  for i = #tbl, 2, -1 do
    math.randomseed( os.time() )
    math.random();math.random();math.random();math.random();
    local j = math.random(i)
    tbl[i], tbl[j] = tbl[j], tbl[i]
  end
  return tbl
end

local times = {
    0.5,
    1.0,
    1.5,
    2.0,
    2.5,
    3.0,
    3.5,
    4.0
}


local timeunits = {} --refer to line 49, I did not want to do it like that...

function nnumbersto8(amount)

    local sum = 0
    local numbs = {}

    times = shuffle(times) --reshuffle the set

    for i = 1,amount,1 do --add first x values together
        sum = sum + times[i]
        numbs[i] = times[i]
    end

    if sum ~= 8 then sleep(0.1) nnumbersto8(amount) return end --if they are not 8, repeat process with cooldown to avoid stack overflow

    --return numbs -- This doesn't work for some reason, nothing gets returned outside the function

    timeunits = numbs
end

nnumbersto8(5) -- manual run it for now
print(unpack(timeunits))
```

There must be a simpler way, right?
Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your example shows the points in your `times` table are regular, is that always the case? also why are you "shuffling" is there a reason for this? it seems unnecessary and could lead to checking the same set multiple times

Comment: @Nifim Yes it is

Comment: @Nifim I'm shuffling because I want the numbers to be "random" each time. I'm currently generating some placeholder data for some project, which needs a few hundreds of values

Comment: so you are looking for a set of values that add up to `8` taken randomly from `times` that should scale for a value where the result will be hundreds of values

Comment: Exactly, but forget about the hundreds of values. Right now I need to make the function work for just 1-5 values. Basically nnumbersto8() will take 1,2,3,4,5 as its argument, nothing more. I will repeat this process a few times later on, but that's not the issue.

Comment: How important is it that all subsets that add to your target are equally likely?

Comment: Not too much, it "should look random" tho, no clear patterns or too many repetitions

Comment: There is only 1 unique set of values to get to 8 with 5 values from `times` these makes for a lack luster randomness.

Comment: It's okay, I might add a few more values some time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method that will work for large numbers of elements, and will pick a random solution with theoretically even likelihood for each.

```
function solution_node (value, count, remainder)
    local node = {}
    node.value = value
    node.count = count
    node.remainder = remainder
    return node
end

function choose_solutions (node1, node2)
    if node1 == nil then
        return node2
    elseif node2 == nil then
        return node1
    else
        -- Make a random choice of which solution to pick.
        if node1.count < math.random(node1.count + node2.count) then
            node2.count = node1.count + node2.count
            return node2
        else
            node1.count = node1.count + node2.count
            return node1
        end
    end
end

function decode_solution (node)
    if node == nil then
        return nil
    end

    answer = {}
    while node.value ~= nil do
        table.insert(answer, node.value)
        -- This causes the solution to be randomly shuffled.
        local i = math.random(#answer)
        answer[#answer], answer[i] = answer[i], answer[#answer]
        node = node.remainder
    end
    return answer
end

function random_sum(tbl, count, target)
    local choices = {}
    -- Normally arrays are not 0-based in Lua but this is very convenient.
    for j = 0,count do
        choices[j] = {}
    end
    -- Make sure that the empty set is there.
    choices[0][0.0] = solution_node(nil, 1,  nil)

    for i = 1,#tbl do
        for j = count,1,-1 do
            for this_sum, node in pairs(choices[j-1]) do
                local next_sum = this_sum + tbl[i]
                local next_node = solution_node(tbl[i], node.count, node)
                -- Try adding this value in to a solution.
                if next_sum <= target then
                    choices[j][next_sum] = choose_solutions(next_node, choices[j][next_sum])
                end
            end
        end
    end

    return decode_solution(choices[count][target])
end

local times = {
    0.2,
    0.3,
    0.5,
    1.0,
    1.2,
    1.3,
    1.5,
    2.0,
    2.5,
    3.0,
    3.5,
    4.0
}

math.randomseed( os.time() )
local result = random_sum(times, 5, 8.0)
print("answer")
for k, v in pairs(result) do print(v) end
```

Sorry for my code.  I haven't coded in Lua for a few years.

Comment: your answer does not seem to specify the number of values returned. the OP specified in the original `nnumbersto8` function with `amount` so for `nnumbersto8(5)`, it would return the 5 values that add up to 8.

Comment: @Nifim Oops, fix coming soon.

Comment: Fixed.  It now accepts the number of arguments.  All solutions should show up (modulo quirks of the random number generator) with equal likelihood.

Answer (score 1):

There are no solutions for 1, 2 and for values greater than 5, so the function only accepts 3, 4 and 5.

Here we are doing a shallow copy of the `times` table then we get a random index from the copy and begin searching for the solution, removing values we use as we go.

```lua
local times = {
    0.5,
    1.0,
    1.5,
    2.0,
    2.5,
    3.0,
    3.5,
    4.0
}

function nNumbersTo8(amount)
  
    if amount < 3 or amount > 5 then 
      return {}
    end
  
    local sum = 0
    local numbers = {}
    
    local set = {table.unpack(times)}
    
    for i = 1, amount - 1, 1 do
        local index = math.random(#set)
        local value = set[index]
        
        if not (8 < (sum + value)) then
            sum = sum + value
            table.insert(numbers, value)
            table.remove(set, index)
        else
            break
        end        
    end
    local reminder = 8 - sum

    for _,v in ipairs(set)do
        if v == reminder then
            sum = sum + v
            table.insert(numbers, v)
            break
        end
    end
    
    if #numbers == amount then
        return numbers
    else
        return nNumbersTo8(amount)
    end
end
```

```lua
for i=1,100 do
  print(table.unpack(nNumbersTo8(5)))
end
```

Example response:

```
1.5 0.5 3   2   1
3   0.5 1.5 1   2
2   3   1.5 0.5 1
3   2   1.5 1   0.5
0.5 1   2   3   1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the [*subset sum problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) with an extra restriction on the number of elements you are allowed to choose.

The solution is to use Dynamic Programming similar to regular Subset Sum, but add an extra variable that indicates how many items you have used.

This should go something among the lines of:

```
Failing stop clauses:
DP[-1][x][n] = false, for all x,n>0  // out of elements
DP[i][-1][n] = false, for all i,n>0  // exceeded X items
DP[i][x][n] = false n < 0            // Passed the sum limit. This is an optimization only if all elements are non negative.
Successful stop clause:
DP[i][0][0] = true for all i >= 0

Recursive formula:
DP[i][x][n] = DP[i-1][x][n] OR DP[i-1][x-1][n-item[i]]  // Watch for n<item[i] case here.
              ^                       ^
      Did not take the item        Used the item
```